# How to get all users in a list Twitter API?

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

Is there a way to access all members in a list?
Currently, I can only see the first 20 members?
Specifically, I'm using python and tweepy.

Comment: If only there was a BigQuery table for it, there is even an export script https://github.com/twitterdev/twitter-for-bigquery GitHub Archive does it for GitHub for example https://www.githubarchive.org/

Comment: @self: maybe it is against Twitter's ToS: https://twittercommunity.com/t/can-i-release-mined-tweets-for-research/13463

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Tweepy, this can be facilitated by using the Cursor class Tweepy provides, which implements an appropriate iterator for the model returned to you depending on your desired method call. In your case, you want to initialize a Cursor with the `list_members()` method and parameters for the list owner and the list slug (see https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/lists/members).

Example (modified from http://packages.python.org/tweepy/html/code_snippet.html#pagination):

```
import tweepy
api = tweepy.API() # Don't forget to use authentication for private lists/users.

# Iterate through all members of the owner's list
for member in tweepy.Cursor(api.list_members, 'list_owner', 'slug').items():
    # Do something with member...
```

I wish I could link you some up-to-date documentation, but the only thing I can find is this version [1.4 documentation about using Cursors](http://packages.python.org/tweepy/html/cursor_tutorial.html). This strategy is still the recommended way of doing pagination/iteration of results from the Twitter API resources in Tweepy.

Comment: Also if you already have a list ID: ``tweepy.Cursor(api.list_members, list_id=list_id)``

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about tweepy. But twitter's REST API limits results. At the end of result it gives some kind of pointer to next page. Use that pointer :) https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
user = tweepy.api.get_user('you or nick') 

print user.screen_name
print user.followers_count

for friend in user.friends():
  print friend.screen_name
```