# Tweepy: TweepError: [{'code': 112, 'message': 'You must specify either a list ID or a slug and owner.'}]

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to print the celebrity list from [this twitter handle](https://twitter.com/BuzzEdition/lists/the-celebrity-list/members?lang=en), but I always get an error. From the [tweepy documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.lists) and [stackoverlow solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058858/how-to-get-all-users-in-a-list-twitter-api). My code looks correct. Can anyone please help me?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jubin/PycharmProjects/MLTwitterBotsDetection/BotsDataDownload.py", line 40, in <module>
    bot_list = api.list_members('E meth','i2p', tweepy.Cursor)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 245, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 229, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp, api_code=api_error_code)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'code': 112, 'message': 'You must specify either a list ID or a slug and owner.'}]


import tweepy
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key,access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

for member in tweepy.Cursor(api.list_members, 'BuzzFeed', 'The Celebrity List').items():
    print (member)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying a list name that doesn't exist.

Based on the URL you included in your question:

```
https://twitter.com/BuzzEdition/lists/the-celebrity-list/members
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The username should be `"BuzzEdition"`, not `"BuzzFeed"`, and the list name should be `"the-celebrity-list"`, not `"The Celebrity List"`.

The stack trace in your question, similarly, appears to be trying to retrieve a list under the invalid username `"E meth"`. Twitter usernames cannot contain spaces.

Comment: I tried this, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution.